# NetBeans, Turn off **ANY** auto indentation / auto formatting

Tags: netbeans, auto-indent

I have just tried out NetBeans and I really like it.
But what drives me crazy is the horrible automatic code formatting !

If I make an indentation, *I want* **that** *indentation*, but NetBeans keeps going straight the formatting style defined in Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Formatting.

Just for example, let's say I want to do the following:

```
namespace cn {
    // this has 1 indentation
        // this has 2 indentations
        class Foo;
}
```

NetBeans turns it into:

```
namespace cn {
    // this has 1 indentation
        // this has 2 indentations
    class Foo;
}
```

Itdoes automatically remove one of the 2 indentations when typing any character except than `/`.

### Is there an option I have missed that turns off any auto indentation ?

*Even this might turn off the very well de-indentation when using a curly brace closed.*

Comment: What makes it worse is that the indentation doesn't work most of the time, even for pure PHP code. If we add some templating engine / HTML / CSS / JS to the mix I find myself spending quarter of my time actually fixing the indentation.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the very same thing and I'm afraid the answer is no.

I'm using Netbeans for PHP and if I go under Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Formatting there is an option called "number of space per indent", the problem is that it can't be set to 0.
Frustrating to say the least, as I would have expected to be able to choose whether to indent or not any time I wanted using my keyboard.